# Extracting Wanted Data from the Raw Cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have been trying to extract the required data from a single cell and I have tried using some common formulas but its not working for all the cells exactly.

I would appreciate your help in this regards.

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WS6EKTpA02LUxKCE1t-h08VrgDhiy0mGR4AhZjScagE/edit?usp=sharing)

Formula 1

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND(C2,A2)-1)
```

Formula 2

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,len(A2)-FIND(") ",A2)),6),")",""),"(","")),"|","")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I duplicated your tab and entered the following formula in cell E2:

```
=ArrayFormula(ifna(regexextract(A2:A,"\[\s\]\s(.+)?\s\((.+)\)")))
```

### Explanation

- `\[\s\]\s` - find `[ ]`
- `(.+)?\s\(` - extract everything after it until the next occurence of  `(`
- `(.+)\)` - extract everything after the above  `(` and before the next occurence of `)`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: The first time I've tried @ztiaa answer it didn't work... don't know why. I kept investigating REGEX and gave it another try, and it did... You'd probably prefer that. I leave my answer just as a memory, and if it's useful for someone else in another scenario

---

Honestly, I don't handle regex as @ztiaa, but what I've found difficult about your example is that there are sometimes more than one opening parenthesis... that's why I looked for a way of finding the last appearance of "(". You can learn more about this workaround [here](https://trumpexcel.com/find-characters-last-position/)

I changed "@" with "CUT HERE" in my example, just in case "@" may appear in your example. With that in mind, you can set these two formulas:

> =ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="","",MID(A3:A,5,FIND("CUT HERE",SUBSTITUTE(A3:A,"(","CUT
> HERE",LEN(A3:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3:A,"(",""))))-5)))
>
> =arrayformula(if(A3:A="","",mid(A3:A,FIND("CUT HERE",SUBSTITUTE(A3:A,"(","CUT
> HERE",LEN(A3:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3:A,"(",""))))+1,FIND(")",A3:A,FIND("CUT
> HERE",SUBSTITUTE(A3:A,"(","CUT
> HERE",LEN(A3:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3:A,"(",""))))+1)-FIND("CUT
> HERE",SUBSTITUTE(A3:A,"(","CUT
> HERE",LEN(A3:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3:A,"(",""))))-1)))

The second one is really long because it has to find the amount of characters in between brackets. But it appears to work. Probably there's a more ellegant way with Regex, I repeat :)

Look in J and K of your example:

[image]